Number of solutions in the positive octant $\mathbb{R}^3_+$ of a polynomial system of equations
Important edit: apparently my conjecture was wrong (see the answer I posted). In any case, I would still be very interested in methods that allows me to find/estimate the number of solutions in the positive octant, so please feel free to add another answer!

Original question: suppose I have a system of $3$ polynomials in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which I know have finitely many solutions. Is there a way to find the number of solutions in the positive octant $\mathbb{R}^3_+$ alone, based on the polynomials' coefficients?
Context: I have a system of $3$ polynomials of degree $2$, which I can write as:
$$
x^\top A_i x = b_i,
$$
with $i = \{1,2,3\}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$. Additionally, I also assume that the matrices $A_i$ are positive semidefinite (with $\mathrm{rank}\,A_i = 2$) and that $b_i > 0$.
Assume that these parameters are chosen so that I never have a positive dimensional solution set. Based on the degrees, I know that the maximal number of real solutions is $8$, and, in fact, it's easy to fabricate an example with $8$ distinct solutions. However, based on the geometry of the problem (it basically boils down to the intersection of three elliptic cylinders), I have a hunch that I will always have only one solution so that $x\in\mathbb{R}^3_+$, i.e., so that each component of $x$ is strictly positive.
How can one attack this problem? It seems frustratingly simple, but I have no clue on how to prove the uniqueness of the solution if we restrict the domain. Thanks!
Edit to answer @RobertIsrael: I have another assumption on the $A_i$ matrices, namely that the $i$-th row and the $i$-th column are identically null, i.e.
$$
A_1=\begin{bmatrix}0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && a_1 && b_1 \\ 0 && b_1 && c_1\end{bmatrix},\,
A_2=\begin{bmatrix}a_2 && 0 && b_2 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 \\ b_2 && 0 && c_2\end{bmatrix},\,
A_3=\begin{bmatrix}a_3 && b_3 && 0 \\ b_3 && c_3 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Basically this means that the elliptic cylinders described above lie along the three axes, and I think this is enough to conclude that we have at most one solution in the positive octant.
I also have some non-trivial dependencies between the elements of the matrices, but I don't think they are relevant for the problem at hand.

Are you trying to do this for a particular set of $A_i$ and $b_i$, or do you think the solution is always unique under the given conditions?

@RobertIsrael I tried to keep the question a bit more general, but I do have some additional assumptions on the $A_i$. I'll edit the question.

Unfortunately, I was able to find a counterexample to my claim, which is:
$$
A_1=\begin{bmatrix}0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1\end{bmatrix},\,
A_2=\begin{bmatrix}2.55 && 0 && -2.45 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 \\ -2.45 && 0 && 2.55\end{bmatrix},\,
A_3=\begin{bmatrix}0.1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 4 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0\end{bmatrix},
$$
which gives two distinct solutions in the positive octant.
